# Amount of heat required to raise the temperature of a balloon which requires no energy for expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics

> Two moles of ideal helium gas are in a rubber balloon at $30^°C$. The balloon is fully expandable and can be assumed to require no energy in its expansion. The temperature of the gas in the balloon is slowly changed to $35°C$. The amount of heat required in raising the temperature is nearly equal to ? (Take gas constant = $8.31 J/mol.K$)

Now, since no energy is required in its expansion I can take work done in its expansion = $0$.
So by first law of thermodynamics,

$$\Delta Q = \Delta U + W$$
Since $W = 0 \implies  \Delta Q = \Delta U$.

But we know that $\Delta Q = n.C_p.\Delta T$ and $\Delta U = n.C_v.\Delta T$ and they give different answers.

I realize that taking work done in expansion is $0$ is wrong. But then what do they mean by no energy is required in its expansion ?

Answer (score 1):

This likely means that the balloon skin itself requires negligible work to expand. However, the gas inside still needs to perform work against the outside pressure so taking the work as zero is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

If there is no energy required to expand the balloon you're right to asume that $W = 0$, so your affirmation $\Delta Q = \Delta U$ is correct.

Now, one can calculate the initial and the final internal energy if you remember that internal energy is proportional to temperature, 
$U = \dfrac{5}{2}Nk_BT$, $N$ being the number of particles in the gas and $k_B$ the Boltzmann constant. All is left is to crunch the numbers.

Comment: Isn't  $U = \dfrac{3}{2}Nk_BT$ for a mono atomic molecule?

Comment: You have ideal gas, ideal helium gas. In case you didn't, there are similar relations for molecules with more degrees of freedom.